# Не запускается Tomcat, помогите

Tags: java, android, apache, tomcat

Сделал все по инструкции, установил все переменные среды, но он все равно не запускается. Вот что выводится в cmd при попытке запуска:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "D:\Tomcat"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\Tomcat"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\Tomcat\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\Tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\Tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Запускается окно батнику и тут же исчезает. По адресу http://127.0.0.1:8080/ ничего нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: откройте командную строку и выполните скрипт запуска (`catalina.bat start`) из нее - тогда вы увидите результат выполнения и окно не закроется. если после этого будет непонятно, почему не работает - добавьте логи в вопрос.

Comment: При его запуске, выводятся те же логи и окно все равно тут же закрывается и у catalina.bat и startup.bat

Comment: допишите в конце батника `pause`, тогда окно не закроется

Comment: Не помогло, единственное что изменилось, это в самой командной строке в конце появляется надпись "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу..."

Comment: Посмотрите есть ли логи и, что в них - D:\Tomcat\logs\catalina.out